# スクレイピングの送信トラフィックの計測

Tags: python, wireshark, tcpdump, tshark

例えば、サンプルとして以下のファイルを実行したとします。
受信トラフィックや送信トラフィックを計測するには具体的にどのようにしたら良いですか？
(ソース https://techacademy.jp/magazine/20930)

```
(python)
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
result = requests.get('https://newspicks.com/') 
data_1 = BeautifulSoup(result.text, 'html.parser')
data_2 = data_1.find_all("div", class_="title _ellipsis")
for item in data_2:
  print(item.getText())
```

Answer (score 1):

> 受信トラフィックや送信トラフィックを計測するには具体的にどのようにしたら良いですか？

[tsharkコマンドの使い方](https://qiita.com/hana_shin/items/0d997d9d9dd435727edf)を参考に実際にトラフィックを表示してみました、参考というより丸写しです。実行した環境は`CentOS Linux release 8.1.1911 (Core)`です。

手順は以下のとおりです。

`tcpdump`コマンドを起動し、パケットキャプチャ取得を開始します。結果ファイルは`test.cap`とします。
(別のターミナルで)質問された方のコードを実行します。
`^C`で`tcpdump`を終了します。

```
# tcpdump -i ens160 not tcp port 22 -w test.cap
tcpdump: listening on ens160, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
^C300 packets captured
331 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

次に`tcpdump`‘の結果ファイルを指定して、`tshark`コマンドを起動します。
以下の例は「全プロトコルの統計情報」の表示です。

```
# tshark -qr test.cap -z io,phs
Running as user "root" and group "root". This could be dangerous.

===================================================================
Protocol Hierarchy Statistics
Filter:

eth                                      frames:300 bytes:43106
  arp                                    frames:225 bytes:13500
  ip                                     frames:63 bytes:28838
    udp                                  frames:30 bytes:4870
      data                               frames:3 bytes:1743
      nbns                               frames:18 bytes:1656
      nbdgm                              frames:5 bytes:1215
        smb                              frames:5 bytes:1215
          mailslot                       frames:5 bytes:1215
            browser                      frames:5 bytes:1215
      llmnr                              frames:4 bytes:256
    tcp                                  frames:33 bytes:23968
      http                               frames:10 bytes:7918
        tcp.segments                     frames:1 bytes:68
        ssl                              frames:8 bytes:7745
          tcp.segments                   frames:2 bytes:3379
            http                         frames:2 bytes:3379
              ssl                        frames:2 bytes:3379
  ans                                    frames:12 bytes:768
===================================================================
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
スクリプトを実行したときの送信量はこの場合、どこを見ればよろしいのでしょうか？？

また、$ tcpdump -i ens160 not tcp port 22 -w test.cap で作られたtest.capをwiresharkで開き、統計、対話をクリックすると以下のようになりましたが、この場合6204バイトが送信量と考えていいのでしょうか？
https://gyazo.com/86b5f2771db03dfba38b1edecd9c07b4

Comment: 「Address B」があなたのmacアドレスのようですので、送受信の方向についての理解は間違っていないと思います。12.1887秒の間に9453バイト(75624bit)送信していて、1秒当たりの平均が6204bitですね。送信量を単純にDuration(計測時間)で割っているようです。推測ですが計測時間を2倍にするとこの値は半分になると思います。

Comment: 非常にわかりやすい説明をありがとうございます！単位なんてどこにも書かれていなかったのに解明してくださって驚きと感謝です。
9453バイト(75624bit)が、スクリプト1回分の下り転送量と判断できるということですね！
計測が初めてなので非常に勉強になりました、ありがとうございました！